# Run exe application inside WPF application, Different between Command and Click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to run an application in WPF application，and Here is the code after I searching the answer。

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetParent", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowWindow")]
    private static extern long ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

       public void ShowWindow(){
       System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox childp = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        {
            Height = 1000,
            Width = 1000
        };
        winform.Child = childp;


         ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe")
         {
              WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
          };

         Process PR = Process.Start(psi);

        // true if the associated process has reached an idle state:
        PR.WaitForInputIdle();
       

        // loading exe to the wpf window:
        SetParent(PR.MainWindowHandle, childp.Handle);
        ShowWindow(PR.MainWindowHandle, 3);
        }
```

and the xaml code is:

```
       <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="localhost">
                <StackPanel>
                    <wfi:WindowsFormsHost  x:Name="winform"/>
                    <Button Command = "{Binding ShowWindowCommand}">Show Window<Button/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="File1">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

But this code didn't run correctly,the mspaint.exe run out of the WPF application,The function `ShowWindow()` is called by Command `ShowWindowCommand` and useless,but if if called by `Click` and change  `PR.WaitForInputIdle();` to `Thread.sleep` ,It works,but why?

Answer (score 1):

The different between Command and Click is:

- Command using to execute ICommand property in the ViewModel class.
- Click using to execute a method defined in code-behind class.

If you want to use the Command, you will need to create a ICommand property and execute the code there. Here is an example:

```
        private ICommand _showPaintCommand;

        public ICommand ShowPaintCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_showPaintCommand == null)
                {
                    _showPaintCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => ShowPaint(),
                        param => true);
                }

                return _showPaintCommand;
            }
        }

        private void ShowPaint()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe")
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
            };

            Process PR = Process.Start(psi);
        }
```

How to create RelyCommand class here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/